# Power BI DAX measure to count items by status at given point of time

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say we have a versioned fact table that contains records about items and their statuses. Each record references an item, update date and its new status. Similar to this:

| ItemId | Updated | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boogie | 19.04.2021 | Resolved |
| Raven | 20.04.2021 | Resolved |
| Raven | 22.04.2021 | Closed |

So item's status is defined by the last known status update. We want to know how many items were in each status at any given point of time. It could look like this in table form:

| Date | Total count | Count of "Closed" | Count of "Resolved" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18.04.2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19.04.2021 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 20.04.2021 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 21.04.2021 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 22.04.2021 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Any ideas on how to build a DAX measure to calculate this (e.g. "Count of "Closed")?

P.S. Note that it is not guaranteed for any given item to have it's version record logged daily (or with any given frequency in general); only *changes* to status are logged and present in the version table.

Comment: Couple of clarifying questions:  
1) Are you currently using a calendar table? 
2) How long are you planning on tracking these things?  10 years back?  2 years back?  Size of the data & longevity will determine how I would answer you (If for only a short time period, then calendar table with calculated columns, if not, measures)

Comment: 1) Yes, I am using a calendar table
2) The data in the "changelog" table would definitely span more than one calendar year, so DATESYTD-based tricks are a no-go. Generally, its several years timeframe, a few thousands of items and on average 10 or so status changes per item (including changing status back and forth e.g. Open->Resolved->Open->smth else).